# Input fields stay blanks with special characters after submitting to DB

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, encoding, character

I'm using codeigniter and have some inputs fields and textareas, When I try to put a character like **é, à, è** in the field and submit this to my DB it will not be saved, the field stay blank

I'm using UTF8 encoding (utf8_general_ci in DB / in my header : charset=utf-8 / and in the config file of codeigniter it's set UTF8

I don't really understand why it doesn't work :/ any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your tables and its fields collation to  **utf8_unicode_ci** or **utf8_genaral_ci** and it should work.

**Edited:**
Then try doing:

```
$yourString = utf8_encode($yourString);
For each of your variables before inserting to DB
```

Hope it helps

Comment: As I said in my question everything in my DB is already in utf8_general_ci

Comment: Well, Instead of this I've change in my config.php in Ci the line : $config['charset'] = 'utf8'; (it was UTF-8) and now I have something like ÃƒÂ©Ã©